# How to unit test NgRx selector observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs, ngrx

I'm trying to override an NgRx Selector and have the overridden value output from the observable.

It appears to me that the call to overrideSelector() is not working as I expect. The result of this override is not reflected in the final assertion when I test the observable.

Given the following minimal reproduction example, how would I get this test to pass?

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { cold } from 'jest-marbles';
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector, select } from '@ngrx/store';

let store: MockStore<any>;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [],
    providers: [provideMockStore({ initialState: { feature: { myValue: 'initial value' } } })]
  });

  store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
});

it('should emit the overridden selector value', () => {
  const featureSelector = createFeatureSelector<any>('feature');
  const mySelector = createSelector(featureSelector, (state: any) => state.myValue);
  const myObservable$ = store.pipe(select(mySelector));

  store.overrideSelector(mySelector, 'some new value');
  store.refreshState();

  const expected = cold('a', { a: 'some new value' });
  expect(myObservable$).toBeObservable(expected); // Fails.  The emmitted value is still 'initial value'
});
```

As an interesting side note.. If I actually subscribe to myObservable$ in the test, then the emitted value there is what I expect.

```
  myObservable$.subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(val); // logs: 'some new value'
  });
```

For some additional context, this is a minimal reproduction.  I actually have a service that exposes the equivalent of myObservable$. Internally this observable is wired up as a store selector (almost as it is here but a bit more complex).  I am trying to test this service and in particular check that the exposed myObservable$ behaves correctly given a certain store arrangement.

Comment: Could you replicate the problem in a StackBlitz app? [Here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lnvayypprgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth-guard.service.spec.ts) would be a starting point.

Comment: @AndreiGătej  Actually,  no I can't replicate it in StackBlitz.  I've pasted the code exactly as it appears here, and only made the changes necessary to have it run under jasmine.  It all works exactly as I expect.  Could this be something specific to jest?

Comment: Interesting. I can't say for sure what's going on, but I think you can find out more if you use the debugger and inspect the source code of the libraries you're using there. If you're using VS Code, this should be easy to set up. I'd be glad to help if needed.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, this test doesn't add no value.

You're creating a selector, mocking the selector, and then testing that the selector is returning the mocked value.

> I am trying to test this service and in particular check that the exposed myObservable$ behaves correctly given a certain store arrangement.

When you mock a selector, it doesn't look at the store arrangement - it just returns the mocked return value.

If you want to test a selector, the easiest way is to use the project method.
See my blog post [How I test my NgRx selectors](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/how-i-test-my-ngrx-selectors#testing-approach-3-projector) or the [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#testing-selectors) for more info.

Comment: Yes,  perhaps I have worded the title of the question incorrectly.  I am not trying to test the selectors.  I am trying to test the service that makes use of these selectors, hence I am trying to mock (override) their output.